# How to display multiple table view controllers like app store?

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image: App store image]

What should i use so that i'm able to display multiple table view controllers in a single view controller... much like App Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping 3 UITableViews isn't much of a great Idea as you would already have to declare 3 NSMutableArrays to fill up these tableViews. You can get the same functionality not with multiple TableViews, but different NSMutableArrays to fill up a single UITableView.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (isPaid)
    {   
        return [self.arrayForPaidApps count];                        
    }
    else if(isFree) {
        return [self.arrayForFreeApps count];
    }
    else {
        return [self.arrayForTopApps count];
    }
}
```

Similarly for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method too and you'll get the required thing.

Just keep reloading the table at the event of clicking Paid, Free or Grossing apps.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the fact that you can switch between "paid", "free" and "top grossing"?

I think that the best approach here would be to have one table controller (since the representation in each case is the same), but to supply the appropriate data from the data source delegate methods depending on the selected choice.

When the user changes the choice at the top, use [tableView reloadData] to pick up the new dataset.

Tim

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that i got your question correctly but .. 
Couldn't be the same table view and change datasource at a certain point ? 
Just like you do when performing a search in a table..